# How I can use the differents font size of a *.ttf file?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-size, truetype

I downloaded differents *.ttf font files.
In these files there is a lot of available sizes.

However, i see no `font-size` attributes in the `@font-face` declaration in css files.

There is style (normal, italic...etc), weight (bold for example), but not any attribute to implement to use the differents size in the file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'dragon';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal; 
  src: local('Dragon'), url('./fonts/dragon.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truetype fonts may include glyphs of different styles and weights (so you can specify what the file contains) but they **scale** so it wouldn't make sense to specify what sizes of fonts the file contains: It contains all of them.

The [`size-adjust` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/size-adjust) allows you to apply a multiplier to the scaling so that different fonts can play better together.